# How to change email string format, to a url format in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, axios

i am trying to make work a GET method endpoint, in a proyect with react, where i need to send a email as parameter in the url, but it fails becouse is not in the correct format, example:

i am sending it, with axios library, like this:

const config = {
url: `${url}/auth/forgot-password?username=${credentials}`,
headers,
};

and its sending it like this: `/auth/forgot-password?username=jsimancas@gmail.com`
but it works if i fix manualy the email format like this: `/auth/forgot-password?username=jsimancas%40gmail.com`

i mean i need to change the @ for a %40 to make it works. Does exist a method in react to fix the email format in a URL???

thanks in advance.

Comment: you're looking for [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Comment: Thank you @DerekPollard, just what i needed!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) just worked perfect!!

Thanks to [Derek Pollard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2020002/derek-pollard) for the answer! :)

Comment: If you are adding a self-answer then it might be useful to mark it accepted. Also, adding thanks for someone's comment is nice, but not really necessary unless you copy their comment.

Comment: i will mark this answer as accepted, but i can do it after 2 days i made this post ...

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
let email = 'test@gmail.com'
console.log(email.replace('@', '%40'))
```

Comment: this breaksdown for `+` and any other acceptable special char allowed in emails but not in URLs